# Using google map's containsLocation() in java

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I make use of google map's containsLocation() in java? It is present in the geometry library. I am not able to find the URL from where I can make an HTTP Request.I need to call it from java because I am using this function in benchmark testing.Is there a way I can pass polygon and point location to containsLocation() in java and get whether the point is outside or inside the polygon.

Comment: You may want to look into the Bounds class of the com.google.maps.android.geometry library  http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/index.html?com/google/maps/android/geometry/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't find an alternative to use containsLocation() in java I hosted my two implementations on AWS and performed benchmark tests on the sites itself.